# Angular Unittest change data of observable in constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have scenario where I put a subscription on a function of a service in the constructor. I was able to test that function but I want to test it with different data inputs.
this is my test:

```
class MockService {
  testFunction = (): Observable<any> => of({id:1});
}

describe('function in const test', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let component: TestComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      providers: [
        { provide: TestService, useClass: MockService },
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should do test', () => {

  });
});
```

constructor:

```
constructor(private testService: TestService) {

   this.testService
      .testFunction()
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {

        },
      });
}
```

this work fine. But now I want to change {id:1} into a empty {} to test different scenarios but I dont know how. Does someone has a suggestion?

Thx a lot

Comment: You can leave the createComponent inside each test, and before creating it, you can change your mock implementation.

Comment: @CaioOliveira can you provide an example, that would be nice